# How to work with index.html, ui.router, and redirect back to home

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I use for testing python simpleserver to test my angular app.  I new to ui.router and trying to get index.html work properly and when trying to go home using e.g.

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="/">MyApp</a>
```

To navigate back to home or index.html

**Code**

```
"use strict";
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);

mainApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/#');
    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        });
});

mainApp.controller('mainController',
    function($state, $log, $scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        $scope.test = 'foobar';
    }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated to fix it.

[Problem Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/auszWR0nXb38ZvYBkGQP?)

Comment: what is going wrong..?`redirect back to home` means what, you have only one state there..

Comment: Maybee rephrase my nav is showing twice.  Did you look at the plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering `index.html` again inside your `ui-view` div, so techically you should have `html` that would have your home page content

**myHomePage.html**

```
<div class="home-page">
  Its home page

  {{test}}
</div>
```

**State**

```
$stateProvider
.state('/', { //<-- here it should be some stateName rather than using `/`
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'myHomePage.html', //<--changed here
  controller: 'mainController'
});
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/abSLUXcw5Pfp0hDF8teu?p=preview)